# Is rouge syntax highlighting meant to highlight non-base functions in R?

Tags: r, jekyll, syntax-highlighting, rouge

I'm trying to understand the `rouge` syntax highlighter and in particular use it to highlight R code.  Ultimately it's for a website built with `jekyll` but I've been able to isolate my problems to just `rouge` (eg I use `rougify` on sample code to produce inspectable HTML).

My problem is that most of my code is given class = "n", which I think stands for "name" and is not distinguishable from arbitrary variables.  Most CSS for syntax highlighters I think leaves code of class "n" untouched.  Here's an example of what's generated from `library(ggseas)`:

```
<span class="n">library</span><span class="p">(</span><span class="n">ggseas</span><span class="p">)</span><span class="w">
```

From what I understand of the discussion on [this pull request](https://github.com/jneen/rouge/pull/383), `rouge` highlighting of R only worked at all from early June.  Looking at what I'm pretty sure is the [key bit of code](https://github.com/jneen/rouge/blob/master/lib/rouge/lexers/r.rb) in the source for `rouge`, I *think* that only functions in the variable `PRIMITIVE_FUNCTIONS` are going to be highlighted.  In other words, by leaving all non primitive functions unhighlighted `rouge` is working as it should, it just has got a very limited sense of R syntax.

My question is, have I understood it right?

I need things like `library()` and `ggplot()` to be highlighted even though they aren't primitive functions in the base package of R.  If I have understood things correctly, I will either have to hack the source of `rouge` to include more functions or try to move to something else.

Comment: Did you try to use [Pygments](http://pygments.org/) highlighter ?

Comment: I always used to have pigments but it was getting increasingly rickety in the Jekyll-ruby-Python tool chain as the website grew. Then the Jekyll upgrade to 3.x with a change of computer seems to have killed it altogether. Basically, moving from pygments is what prompts the question.

Comment: This is not directly what you're looking for, but you might try to adapt the approach used in [Nvim-R](https://github.com/jalvesaq/Nvim-R) plugin for vim, as it updates the list of loaded packages from the R environment to highlight library functions. Perhaps you could do a one-off call to R just to populate such a list of functions and then inject that into your CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using `rouge` for R syntax highlighting for a little while, so I can confirm that it has worked in `rouge` for longer than just this month and also that it does a pretty decent job (*personal opinion*).

I have a [GitHub pages](https://pages.github.com) site generated using `jekyll` and I went through the same process of switching over to `rouge` as the highlighter a little while ago.  But it is working well now for R code.  Below is an example screenshot of my site (with some extra code that I added to benefit this post).

[image: R code on a GitHub pages site using rouge]

The code on the page for `library(ggseas)` and `library("ggseas")` (the way I usually write it) is as you suggested:

```
<span class="n">library</span><span class="p">(</span><span class="n">ggseas</span><span class="p">)</span> 
<span class="n">library</span><span class="p">(</span><span class="s2">"ggseas"</span><span class="p">)</span>
```

As you can see, the special highlighting of `PRIMITIVE_FUNCTIONS` refers to the highlighting like we see in the for-loop for the words `for` and `in`.

However, this is the same way that highlighting works in the popular IDE Studio with regards to `ggplot()` and `ggsea`.  Only `library()` (and also some other functions like `require()`) are not included in the list of `PRIMITIVE_FUNCTIONS`, and so do not get highlighted as they should:

[image: R code in the RStudio IDE]

So, I'm curious what your code looked like before that you can't get with `rouge`.
If you only need to fix highlighting for `library()` and `require()` (and probably a few others), then you should be able to just add them to the list of `PRIMITIVE_FUNCTIONS` as you surmised.  But if you want special highlighting for all non-base functions, then it will get more complicated.

In case it helps, I have posted the last part of my `_config.yml` file for my `jekyl` generated site.

```
# Build settings
destination: _site
paginate: 10
permalink: /:year/:title/
markdown: kramdown #redcarpet
highlighter: rouge

#redcarpet:
#  extensions: ["no_intra_emphasis", "fenced_code_blocks", "autolink", "tables", "strikethrough", "superscript", "with_toc_data"]
#redcarpet:
#  extensions: ["no_intra_emphasis", "fenced_code_blocks", "autolink", "tables", "with_toc_data"]

kramdown:
  # use Github Flavored Markdown
  input: GFM
  auto_ids: true
  syntax_highlighter: rouge
  # do not replace newlines by <br>s
  hard_wrap: false

gems: ['jekyll-paginate']
exclude: ['README.md', 'Gemfile', 'Gemfile.lock', 'screenshot.png']
```

---

I also just noticed that it doesn't color code the parenthesis and braces, which is desirable.